# How to pass a model to the form without triggering validation (before editing)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using thymeleaf form and hibernate, I want to pass a model to the form, populate its values in the view, then validate and create this object.
Problem is, when I pass the model to the form I get a validation error.

Following this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf

Full project downloadable here: https://github.com/pyrovoice/BusTraining.git

Mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/createbusvehicle")
public String createBusVehicleDisplay(BusVehicle busVehicle) {
    return "createBusVehicle";
}

@PostMapping("/createbusvehicle")
public String checkAndCreateBusVehicle (@Valid BusVehicle newBusVehicle, BindingResult bindingResultModel, Model model) {
    busVehiculeRepository.save(newBusVehicle);
    return "mainpage";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/createBusVehicle}" th:object="${busVehicle}" method="post">
<p>plateNumber: <input type="text" th:field="*{plateNumber}" /></p>
<p>passengerCapacity: <input type="text" th:field="*{passengerCapacity}" /></p>
<select name="color">
    <option th:each="colorOpt : ${T(com.grazzini.model.BusVehicleColor).values()}"
            th:value="${colorOpt}" th:text="${colorOpt.displayValue}"></option>
</select>

<select name="type">
    <option th:each="typeOpt : ${T(com.grazzini.model.BusVehicleType).values()}"
            th:value="${typeOpt}" th:text="${typeOpt.displayValue}"></option>
</select>


<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
```

the field that creates an issue in BusVehicle:

```
@NotNull
@Min(0)
@Max(70)
@Column(name = "BUSVEHICULE_PASSENGERCAPACITY")
private int passengerCapacity;
```

When removing BusVehicle busVehicle from the createBusVehiculeDisplay method, I have an error "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'busVehicle' available as request attribute". With it, I have "Field error in object 'busVehicle' on field 'passengerCapacity': rejected value [null]; [...]"

Answer (score 1):

Change int to Integer, also remove @NotNull from BusVehicle constructor as well.

```
@NotNull
@Min(0)
@Max(70)
@Column(name = "BUSVEHICULE_PASSENGERCAPACITY")
private Integer passengerCapacity;
```

Also you need to correct the FORM post URL to /createbusvehicle instead of /createBusVehicle in createBusVehicle.html file.

Comment: yeah but the goal is to have the validation AND be able to use it like in the example...

Comment: @Lymn Updated the answer, which is working correctly for me.